# Assign entities to entity with checkboxes

Tags: symfony, checkbox, doctrine-orm, associations, formbuilder

So let's say I have two tables: `permissions`, and sort of a join table between `users` and `permissions` that we'll call `permission_list`

`permission_list` has `user_id` and `permission_id`.

`permission` has the name of the permission and a keyname for use elsewhere in the code.

Now I have an assign permissions page, that currently uses a dropdown list of all the available permissions. What I want to have is a list of checkboxes, where permissions in the users list are checked already, and unchecking them removes those records, and checking new ones adds new records.

Does Symfony2 have a built-in way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question [How to render a checkbox that is checked by default with the symfony2 Form Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583724/how-to-render-a-checkbox-that-is-checked-by-default-with-the-symfony2-form-build)

Form Builder has a lot of great features that will help you accomplish what you are looking for.

That link references this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html that has a ton of info but he gives a good suggestion.  Let me know if thats not clear enough.