# Symfony checkbox checked by default, but not if unchecked after persisted

Tags: javascript, symfony, checkbox

Spoiler alert : this question has been asked numerous times over the years but sofar i've seen no working solutions. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583724/how-to-render-a-checkbox-that-is-checked-by-default-with-the-symfony2-form-build) for instance

I'm developping an application based on a Symfony 2.8 version.

I have an entity with a boolean that i map in the formType with a CheckboxType.

What i need is :

- if this is a new Entity, the checkbox is checked
- if the user has unchecked the checkbox, then persisted, i want the checkbox unchecked
- if i reopen the form if the user has checked the checkbox, then
  persisted, i want the checkbox checked if i reopen the form

This said, i've tried many "solutions" that have been suggested over the topics

**1) In the Entity**

i've set my boolean attribute to true => FAIL : the checkbox is not checked by default

```
class MyEntity
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean")
   */
  private $enabled = true;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->enabled = true;
  }
}
```

**2) In the FormType**

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('enabled', CheckboxType::class, [
        'required' => false,
        'empty_data' => true,
      ]);
  }
```

This 'empty_data' => true (or 'empty_data' => 1, or whatever) works "partially" : 
It displays the correct checkbox state AFTER a persistance, but does not check the checkbox by default => FAIL

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('enabled', CheckboxType::class, [
        'required' => false,
        'data' => true,
      ])
  }
```

It does check the checkbox by default, BUT if a user uncheck the checkbox and persists, the reloaded form still shows the checkbox checked, even if the persisted state is unchecked => FAIL 
this is expected as stated [in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#data)

*Since this entity is not the main form entity : a subform* (in a Collection), i also tried to set the [compound attribute](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#compound) to true in the CheckboxType, with no effect.

**3) Setting the value in the controller when instanciating the form**

this is not a possible option since the checkbox is not in the main Entity/FormType

**=> My method**

Sofar, the only "working solution" i found is to check the checkbox when adding a new block of this Collection using javascript :

```
$(element).prop('checked', true)
```

This is less than optimal...

Do you have a solution for this with SF >=2.8 (2.8 is my version) ? The solution being Symfony side.

Comment: Did you update your database when you tried solution 1? In my project it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $builder->add('enabled', CheckboxType::class, array(
        'attr' => array('checked' => 'checked'),
    ));
```

don't forget to set to true before persist:

```
$obj->setCheckboxValue(true);
```

Comment: 1) i don't think that it would work as i explained : i don't want the checkbox checked ALL THE TIME, only by default. The user can uncheck, so i want to persit it unchecked, then if reloaded show the unchecked. 2) The second part of your response is a no-go for me : my checkbox is not in the main entity, so i would have to loop in the the preflush wich is a costly extra step.